# Get the list of keys updated in the last 24 hours

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I am working on `Hyperledger fabric` and I want to show my client the list of keys whose corresponding values have been updated in the past 24 hours as this lets my client identify the number of transactions daily.

My idea is to write a function in `chaincode` that does the following things:

> 1. Iterate through all the keys
> 2. get history for each key using getHistoryForKey
> 3. form the history, Identify if there was an update made in the last 24 hours.

Is there a better and direct way instead? 
I am writing `chaincoe` in `nodeJS`

Comment: Depending on how frequently you need the list, you may also consider keeping a running list, i.e. as soon as a key is updated, its added to the running queue.

Comment: Do you mean that I add a new key value par to the ledger which tracks the keys updated in last 24 hours?

Comment: I was thinking of a simple data structure of "key" and "last updated" value. When a transaction takes place, the key is also inserted/updated in this simple data structure.